# Black Screen after updates 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, brightness

I have a black/dark screen booting Ubuntu 18.04 after an update.

Interestingly, when I click on the volume up/down, I can *very* faintly see the outline of where it would be (and it gives me audio cues).

I am aware of this common [black screen post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).
I have attempted:

1. Replaced the `quiet splash` with `no splash` and `nomodeset`.
2. Added `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line
3. Press `Fn`+ `F9` (which should increase screen brightness for my laptop, but does not?).

This problem is specific to 4.15.0-74-generic, and does not occur with -72 or -70.

**Edit01:**
ASUS Strix ROG GL503V Laptop with both Intel HD Graphics 630 (According to Bios) and NVidia GeForce 1080 GTX graphics card, but the driver is an Intel driver (i915).

I ran `lspci -k` in the terminal of a prior version (-72):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIBIW.png]

**Edit 02:**
After *disabling Secure Boot*, `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` returns:

(base) marco@marco-GL503VD:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1bb0
Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

and `sudo modprobe nvidia` now returns nothing (it just repeats marco@...)?!

When I look under Software and Updates under Additional Drivers, NVIDIA Corportation: GP107M[...] is selected, and under that metapackage nvidia-driver-435.

Thank you for the assistance and the patience.

Comment: `nouveau.modeset=0` is relevant only to Nvidia adapters.

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers? Which one and how?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion and thank you for the patience. I updated it. Nonetheless, still not sure what the problem is @ boot with the newest version.

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as an image. You can copy text and paste it. The problem is that the driver didn't build. Is Secure boot disabled in BIOS. What does `sudo modprobe nvidia` output?

Comment: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Required key not available.`

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance despite me being such the hassle. And unfortunately I don't think so? Apologies. As mentioned in edit02, I disabled secure boot. `sudo modprobe nvidia` returns nothing (rather than key not found) and `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` shows similarly. I'm not too techy so I'm not sure if this indicates there's an issue with the driver